# when doing "php artisan migrate" i got: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'. (I am using PHPSTORM 2018.3.4)

Tags: php, mysql

I drop the DB and then create it again. 
This is after i drop; (Migration & user migrated successfully)

Migration table created successfully.

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

In Connection.php line 458:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Comment: So the table exists when you run a migration. Check that it's actually dropped, and that you're not having multiple migrations that attempts to create the table .

Comment: "_Base table or view already exists_" or "_1071 Specified key was too long_", which one is it?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users' already exists @kerbholz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    //
}
```

in provider folder find Appserviceprovider.php your boot function should be look like this 
and don't forget to add `use Schema;` at the top